# Prohibit multiple GAM connections

Tags: genexus, genexus-gam

I am looking for an option in the GAM to prohibit the connection of the same user from different PCs.

The "Allow Multiple Concurrent Web Sessions Security Policy" property works the opposite of what I would like as it destroys the first connection established.

What I would like is that the second user trying to connect gets an error.

Are GAM or Genexus handling a similar case? Or do I have to create something myself, perhaps with additional attributes?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with the default behavior of that property.
If you want to do that, you'll need to program it yourself, maybe using the GAMSession external object.

Comment: Do you have an idea on this? I'm trying to look for methods of Gamsession or gamuser but I can't find something interesting.